# decoding and parsing nested json Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing

I want to parse this [json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYOVY.png) and decode and add them into list. However, couldn't find a way to that. I tried this:

```
struct flightsPost: Codable {
    var data: flightDate
}


struct flightDate: Codable {
    var origin: String
    var destination: String
    var price: Int
    var airline: String
    var flight_number: String
    var departure_at: String
    var return_at: String
    var transfers: String
    var expires_at: String
}
```

Couldn't find a place and how to put dates these structs. Please help I am really struggling.

Comment: `var data: flightDate` ->  `var data: [String: flightDate]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is wrong. The data child is not a single object but a collection of type `[String:flightDate]` or if you decode it with a custom dateformatter `[Date:flightDate]`.

```
struct flightsPost: Codable {
    var data: [String:flightDate]
}
```

Comment: thanks but since String part is keep changing how can I map it?

Comment: like : return posts.map {.init(name: $0.data["2022-09-30"]?.origin, desc: $0.data["2022-09-30"]?.destination)
        }

Comment: @MedetDönmez map it to what? But in general if you have a collection of a collection use `.flatMap`. What is `posts` in this conext`.